# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.- Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress

This code is working fine when running locally. When I upload this in [000webhost](https://in.000webhost.com/) and use the path of bundle.js in WordPress page then facing this error.
I am getting the above-mentioned error without `_registerComponent`. Everywhere there is a solution for the error with `_registerComponent`.

Also I am getting the value of `document.getElementById("app")` as null.

```js
app.js

import React from "../node_modules/react/index";
import { render } from "../node_modules/react-dom/index";
import Plans from "./components/Plans";
//Import CSS
import "./styles/styles.scss";

const App = () => (
      <div>
      <Plans/>
      </div>
  );
var app = document.getElementById("app");
console.log("app",document.getElementById("app"))
render(<App/>, app);
```

```html
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div> 
    <script  src="./bundle.js"></script>   
</body>

</html>
```

```html
    Code used in WordPress
    <html>
     <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script async src="https://unvisitable-bows.000webhostapp.com/react-widget-subscription-plans/react-widget-subscription-plans/public/bundle.js" crossorigin></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do [any of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Uncaught+Invariant+Violation%3A+Target+container+is+not+a+DOM+element) help? Not all of them have anything to do with `_registerComponent`

Comment: what is `app` in this line of code `render(<App/>, app)`

Comment: Sorry, I had missed pasting  var app = document.getElementById("app");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are not using `index.html` in wordpress you will need to add root container div for react to use to render your application. Try adding div for `app` in wordpress html i.e `<div id="app"></div>`

```
       <html>
         <head>

        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="app"></div> 
          <script async src="https://unvisitable-bows.000webhostapp.com/react-widget-subscription-plans/react-widget-subscription-plans/public/bundle.js" crossorigin></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, in app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Plans from "./components/Plans";
//Import CSS
import "./styles/styles.scss";

const App = () => (
  <div>
  <Plans/>
  </div>
 );
  ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your variable "app" is undefined. Try this

```
render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thanks, But I have tried this as well and still the problem persists.